# Not found 404 in Laravel 8

Tags: routes, optional-parameters, laravel-8

I have a problem with my optional parameters in routes. The following route works when I go to:
`http://localhost/orders/create/1` but it does not work with `http://localhost/orders/create` and returns a **404 error (not found)**.

```
    Route::name( 'orders.' )->prefix( 'orders' )->group( function(){

        Route::get( '/create/{client?}', [ \App\Http\Controllers\OrderController::class, 'create' ] )->name( 'create' );

    } );

    public function create( Client $client = null ){

        return [ $client ];

    }
```

I already checked and the client with ID=1 exists. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are defining the route /create/{client?} but the /create is not defined, probably your script works with /create/ because the client parameters is optional.

The trailing slash is the problem.